# Convert windows path to unix friendly

Tags: batch-file

Morning,

I need to convert windows path in .bat file to linux friendly, e.g. from `C:\Users\Luga` to `/c/Users/Luga`

only way I found so far is:

```
set profile_new=%UserProfile:\=/%
set profile_new=%profile_new::=%
set profile_new=/%profile_new%
```

which works, but I don't know how to change capital drive letter to lower case, which is unfortunately essential (and I need to be able to do it for every letter possible).

Thanks for any advice

edit: I need it to make docker volumes work - running .bat script on computer that has only docker toolbox.

Used aaaaaa123456789's solution in comments.

Comment: There are only 26 letters; can't you just do a replacement for each one of them manually? Replace `A:` with `/a`, `B:` with `/b`, etc.

Comment: Well I guess I can, but it's not a nice solution and if there's better, I'd like to know.

Comment: This site couldn't really answer what may or may not be better for you, and questions asking for opinion based answers are off topic here. If something does the job then that's fine, if you wish to make it shorter, more efficient, or 'cleverer' looking, then perhaps once you have a working script you could post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for that kind of advice.

Comment: Well, you could do something like this, although you still have got to state all letters: `for %%L in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do call set "profile_new=%%profile_new:%%L:=%%L%%"` (this does not handle the `\ `replacement nor does it precede the `/`). Looping through the letters by their ASCII, for instance, it not that easy in batch scripting and for sure much slower than this approach...

Comment: One problem with this whole question seems to be getting overlooked.  What CYGWIN does is NOT what MINGW64 does is NOT what WSL does.  There is no such thing as a mapping between Windows and Unix paths.. that is dependent on the system.  It depends on HOW and WHERE the windows file system gets mounted. WSL=/mnt/c/Users MINGW64=/c/Users etc etc..  I am assuming that you are using CYGWIN or MINGW64..

Comment: @Luga, so you thought there was a nicer solution but you chose to hardcode 26 set statements instead? Me and aschipfl each gave you a nicer solution.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably leverage [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to do this:

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('
    PowerShell -NoP "$Env:UserProfile.Replace('\','/').Replace(':','').ToLower()"Replace(':','')).ToLower()"
')Do Set "$UserProfile=/%%A"
```

Obviously, in this case, the variable **`%$UserProfile%`** will hold the required value.

---

Alternatively, a [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic) based [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) idea:

```bat
For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%A In ('WMIC FSDir Where^
 "Name='%UserProfile:\=\\%'" Get Name /Value 2^>Nul')Do Set "$%%A%%B" 2>Nul
Set "$Name=/%$Name:\=/%"
```

In this case, the variable **`%$Name%`** would hold your required value.

Comment: For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('
    PowerShell -NoP "$Env:REPLACE_ME.Replace('\','/').Replace(':','').ToLower().Replace(':','').ToLower()"
') Do Set "REPLACE_ME=/%%A"

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed utilities on most *nix on Windows environments that work well.  Doing it by hand is sketchy at best when there are better ways to solve the problem.

If you are using CYGWIN or MINGW, use the **cygpath** utility.

If you are using WSL, use **wslpath**.

If you are using anything else, where the paths are mounted will differ making this converstation moot.  I am sure if you were mounting a samba share, it wouldn't be in /c/

If you need help using them, please refer to **Squashman**'s comment below about the Tour and How-to.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Upper and lower casing has been discussed several times on StackOverflow.  A simple search would find you a plethora of options.

Here is one possible solution for you.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=:" %%G IN ("%UserProfile:\=/%") DO (
    set "drive=%%G"
    set "upath=%%H"
)
CALL :toLower drive
set profile_new=/%drive%%upath%
echo %profile_new%
pause
GOTO :EOF

:toLower str -- converts uppercase character to lowercase
::           -- str [in,out] - valref of string variable to be converted
:$created 20060101 :$changed 20080219 :$categories StringManipulation
:$source https://www.dostips.com
if not defined %~1 EXIT /b
for %%a in ("A=a" "B=b" "C=c" "D=d" "E=e" "F=f" "G=g" "H=h" "I=i"
            "J=j" "K=k" "L=l" "M=m" "N=n" "O=o" "P=p" "Q=q" "R=r"
            "S=s" "T=t" "U=u" "V=v" "W=w" "X=x" "Y=y" "Z=z" "Ä=ä"
            "Ö=ö" "Ü=ü") do (
    call set %~1=%%%~1:%%~a%%
)
EXIT /b
```

Comment: Are letters with umlauts allowed as drive letters?

Comment: Thanks - I did find some upper/lower casing solutions, but was not able to successfully adapt them to my script as I am not too competent in writing batch files.

Comment: @Luga, then they should have been part of your question. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Please read, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, will do better next time.